Convert multiple Markdown files to Latex and insert all Latex files in directory into primary document
I just cobbled together a solution that processes Markdown files to Latex and then inserts all the files into a primary document.  Full credit goes to the many people who posted bits of this solution over the years.  After combing through numerous partial answers on StackExchange and the web more broadly, I am posting my comprehensive solution for everyones' benefit.
Elegant?  Nope.   Efficient?  Doesn't matter given modern hardware :).  Opportunities to improve?  Endless.   I like to copy all the MD files into the checklistsMD directory for processing but that is certainly not necessary.
This works on Mac.

Create folders


checklistsMD
checklistsTex


create files


MakeBook.sh.
makelist.tex


Make executable with chmod +x MakeBook.sh.
Run with ./MakeBook.sh in directory that contains the two folders and two files listed above
Add this inside the document portion of your primary doc and you are good to go: \input{makelist.tex}

Contents of MakeBook.sh **Don't forget to adjust your paths!
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copy md files from Vault
cp thesource/BuildBook/checklistsMD

# Convert all md to tex
find BuildBook/checklistsMD -iname "*.md" -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc "${0}" -o "${0%.md}.tex"' {} \;

# Move tex to correct folder
mv BuildBook/checklistsMD/*.tex BuildBook/checklistsTex

> makelist.tex
for file in checklistsTex/*.tex; do 
  echo "" >> makelist.tex
  echo "\\newpage" >> makelist.tex
  strFull=`echo "$file" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  strFile=`echo "$strFull" | cut -d'/' -f2`
  strSec=`echo "\section{""$strFile""}"`
  echo $strSec >> makelist.tex
  [[ $file  =~ (([0-9].*)) ]] && echo "\import{checklistsTex}{""${BASH_REMATCH[1]}""}" >> makelist.tex
done

Keep in mind this is customized to produce Latex in the 'makelist.tex` file as follows:
\newpage
\section{2400 Walls}
\import{checklistsTex}{2400 Walls.tex}

\newpage
\section{2600 Slabs}
\import{checklistsTex}{2600 Slabs.tex}

Based on file names like:
2400 Walls.md
2600 Slabs.md


Well, the question was really a self answer, but there are easier solutions:

Make two child files, said (foo.qmd and bar.qmd) with whatever markdown content, and include ina main Quarto markdown file, said, baz.qmd, with structure like that:

    ---
    title: "Markdown with includes"
    format: latex
    ---
    
    # Main document
    
    {{< include foo.qmd >}}
    
    {{< include bar.qmd >}}
    
    This was compiled with \LaTeX


Render baz.qmd with Quarto from Rstudio, from VSCode or from the the console:

$ quarto render baz.qmd


Test the result: Compile baz.tex with your favourite LaTeX engine as and open baz.pdf with your favourite  pdf viewer. Result:


Alternatively, You can also change format: latex by format: pdf to join points 2 and 3 (by default, using xelatex).
Note: If you have de subdocuments in subdirectories, said xyz the obviously the path should be included in the include, e.g.:
{{< include xyz/foo.qmd >}}

And take into account that any path of the child files (to the images, por instance) should be relatives to the main file.
